# android activity to libGdx screen

Tags: android, libgdx

How is it possible to move from an android activity back to a libGdx screen .
I am implementing a facebook API in my libGdx game. Whenever i press the facebook button in my game, it takes me to the android activity which logs me into facebook and displays some information using an Interface in the core project.

```
public void LoginFacebook() {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Now i'm wondering how to achieve the same thing but reversed.

How can i move from my results page (android) to my Mainmenu screen (libgdx core)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Screen of LibGDX is nothing more than a type of View of `AndroidLauncher` activity.

When you open any other activity by using Interface then Activity that having LibGDX view is Paused and fold in background.

You can use Intent to move back to your Libgdx Activity from any activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or possibly by `finish()` you can go back to previous Activity.

Comment: Note however that by calling `startActivity()`, you might end up with multiple instances of your game class running, depending on your manifest options. In this case, it'd be better to finish the activity to return to the original game activity.

Comment: @manabreak i need to be able to recall game which is of type MyGame and use for example Game.SetScreen(MainMenuScreen). How can i pass this value to my facebook android class

Comment: I was able to do it by calling finish() on the login page to go back to the game, and call finish when I login. In the main page (where profile is displayed), if i logout i call finish and create an intent to the login page, and if i press go back to game it will call fish which will lead me to the game automatically. So thanks :)